# How to pull first two characters in a String from a Cell and Print to another cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to program a macro that will take the first two characters in a string, compare them using a switch statement, and then output the corresponding info to another column of cells. I have a script written, but it doesn't seem to do anything. I am new to VBA which is why this is causing me a headache.

I've tried a few different methods I have found online. I've looked at examples using Left() to pull a substring and how to write a switch statement in VB. I'm not sure where my error lies, it seems to compile correctly, but doesn't output anything.

```
Sub PullLocation()
    Dim i As Integer  

    For i = 2 To 170
        Dim contents As String
        contents = Left(Ai, 2)
        Select Case contents
            Case "FC"
                Cells(i, AJ) = "Fort Collins"
            Case "BR"
                Cells(i, AJ) = "Broomfield"
            Case "BO"
                Cells(i, AJ) = "Boulder"
            Case "CC"
                Cells(i, AJ) = "Canon City"
            Case "FR"
                Cells(i, AJ) = "Franktown"
            Case "FM"
                Cells(i, AJ) = "Fort Morgan"
            Case "GU"
                Cells(i, AJ) = "Gunnison"
            Case "GR"
                Cells(i, AJ) = "Granby"
            Case "GJ"
                Cells(i, AJ) = "Grand Junction"
            Case "GO"
                Cells(i, AJ) = "Golden"
            Case "LJ"
                Cells(i, AJ) = "La Junta"
            Case "LV"
                Cells(i, AJ) = "La Veta"
            Case "MO"
                Cells(i, AJ) = "Montrose"
            Case "SA"
                Cells(i, AJ) = "Salida"
            Case "SF"
                Cells(i, AJ) = "State Forest"
            Case "SS"
                Cells(i, AJ) = "Steamboat Springs"
            Case Else

        End Select
    Next i
End Sub
```

It should take in two characters which represent an abreviated city name. It is supposed to output the full city name in another column of cells and ignore any unmatched abbreviations by leaving the cell blank.

I don't get any error messages, but nothing changes in my excel sheet either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing what is happening relates to "AJ" and "Ai". Change AJ to 36. Ai should be changed to "Cells(i,35).Value" (the value at AI and whatever row number). I would also put "Dim contents As String" before the beginning of the loop, but keep "contents = Left(Cells(i,35).Value,2)" in the loop.

It would look something like this:

```
Sub PullLocation()
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 2 To 170
        Dim contents As String
        contents = Left(Cells(i, 35).Value, 2)
        Select Case contents
            Case "FC"
                Cells(i, 36) = "Fort Collins"
            Case "BR"
                Cells(i, 36) = "Broomfield"
            Case "BO"
                Cells(i, 36) = "Boulder"
            Case "CC"
                Cells(i, 36) = "Canon City"
            Case "FR"
                Cells(i, 36) = "Franktown"
            Case "FM"
                Cells(i, 36) = "Fort Morgan"
            Case "GU"
                Cells(i, 36) = "Gunnison"
            Case "GR"
                Cells(i, 36) = "Granby"
            Case "GJ"
                Cells(i, 36) = "Grand Junction"
            Case "GO"
                Cells(i, 36) = "Golden"
            Case "LJ"
                Cells(i, 36) = "La Junta"
            Case "LV"
                Cells(i, 36) = "La Veta"
            Case "MO"
                Cells(i, 36) = "Montrose"
            Case "SA"
                Cells(i, 36) = "Salida"
            Case "SF"
                Cells(i, 36) = "State Forest"
            Case "SS"
                Cells(i, 36) = "Steamboat Springs"
            Case Else

        End Select
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I've made these changes, it still seems to not want to do anything. If I step through the script with the debugger, it doesn't fall into any of the cases so maybe the string coming in isn't working? Or maybe the substring isn't right so it just falls through the each case?

Comment: I ran it in mine, and it worked. Are macros enabled on your machine and in the workbook that you are using? Have you selected the sheet that you need as the active sheet?

Comment: Alternatively, if it is doing something, it may be throwing out the else at the end. Try putting after "Case Else" something like "MsgBox "Could not find" & contents"

Comment: I think I got it working now. I added the MsgBox like Parker said, it wasn't displaying anything for the contents so I checked which indexes it was trying to read. One of which was wrong, after changing it, it now works as expected.